# Dart The function 'errorMessage' isn't defined

Tags: dart

I am new to dart and I am learning dart from youtube. And courses that I am following are of 2018. The programs that they created in their videos are not working. I am facing the below issue in all my programs. Anyone, please guide me that why the programs show errors while the programs are running properly in their videos. Is it happening due to an update in dart? or any other reason? Please help to fix this issue. Thanks!
The function 'errorMessage' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'errorMessage', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'errorMessage'.

```
class CustomException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage() {
    return ("Invalid Amount");
  }
}

void AmountException(int amount) {
  if (amount <= 0) {
    throw new CustomException();
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    AmountException(0);
  } catch (e) {
    print(errorMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not calling `errorMessage()` on the exception (`e`).

Comment: Then how to do that. Can you please explain?

Comment: Added an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Bro, Its Working

Comment: Great. If it works and you don't have further questions, please accept my answer. :)

Comment: can you please suggest me updated free course for dart or any updated book related to dart

Comment: Not really. It is ages since I learned Dart and I don't really follow the scene of tutorials. My best suggestion would be to read the official Dart language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour which explains most of the features in Dart with some simple examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the `errorMessage()` message on the exception. Another problem is that your `catch` is set to handle all types of exceptions. Since [`Exception`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.0/dart-core/Exception-class.html) does not have the `errorMessage()` method, you cannot call it.

You should therefore specify the type of exception you want to catch which will allow you to call the `errorMessage()` method on the catched exception:

```
class CustomException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage() {
    return ("Invalid Amount");
  }
}

void AmountException(int amount) {
  if (amount <= 0) {
    throw new CustomException();
  }
}

void main() {
  try {
    AmountException(0);
  } on CustomException catch (e) {
    print(e.errorMessage());
  }
}
```